# Ionic - failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.googleservicesplugin'] > for input string: "+"

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins

The same issue is happening with me

Here is my project.propreties file. I changed everything to 11.0.4 version, but still not working.

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-support-google-services/mobile-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=phonegap-plugin-multidex/mobile-multidex.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v13:27.+
cordova.system.library.5=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-firebase/mobile-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.gms:google-services:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.0.4
```

I add 3 plugin in my Ionic Project.
1 - phonegap-plugin-push (works fine)
2 - cordova-plugin-admob-free (works fine)
3 - cordova-plugin-firebase (i got the error)

When i remove the cordova-plugin-firebase, the build is OK. But when i add the plugin i got the error again.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

please update value as 11.4.2

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/mobile-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-support-google-services/mobile-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3=twitter-connect-plugin/mobile-twitter.gradle
cordova.system.library.7=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+
```

Comment: are you using fcm?.